# Calling parent class constructor in PHP

Tags: php, oop, constructor, laravel

I have a controller

```
use API\Transformer\DataTransformer;
use API\Data\DataRepositoryInterface;

class DataController extends APIController implements APIInterface {

protected $data;

public function __construct(DataRepositoryInterface $data)
{
    $this->data = $data;        
}
```

And in the `APIController`

```
use League\Fractal\Resource\Collection;
use League\Fractal\Resource\Item;
use League\Fractal\Manager;

class APIController extends Controller
{
protected $statusCode = 200;

public function __construct(Manager $fractal)
{       
    $this->fractal = $fractal;

    // Are we going to try and include embedded data?
    $this->fractal->setRequestedScopes(explode(',', Input::get('embed')));

    $this->fireDebugFilters();
}
```

Nothing inside the `APIController __construct()`is being called, I have tried `parent::__construct();` but this errors (see error below) when I try and call a class from the `APIController`

```
Argument 1 passed to APIController::__construct() must be an instance of League\Fractal\Manager, none given, called in /srv/app.dev/laravel/app/controllers/DataController.php on line 12 and defined
```

In other words it is trying to instantiate the `APIController` constructor in the DataController. How can I get it to call the `APIController` constructor before the `DataController`?

Comment: That's correct - it's `parent::__construct()`

Comment: Even with `parent::__construct()` added to DataController, you still need to pass a Manager object to parent constructor. I've never seen parent/child class with differing constructor signatures, not to say that it can't be done, but it does indicate a potential red flag in design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor needs pass all needed objects to the parent constuctor.   The parent constructor needs a Manager object, so you must pass it in if you want to call it.   If DataRepositoryInterface is not a Manager, you'll need to pass a manager into your childs constructor or instantiate an object the necessary class to pass to the parent.

```
 class DataController extends APIController implements APIInterface {

       protected $data;

       public function __construct(Manager $fractal,  DataRepositoryInterface $data) {
            parent::__construct($fractal);
            $this->data = $data;        
        }
  }
```

Or you could instantiate a Manager inside your constuctor

```
     class DataController extends APIController implements APIInterface {

       protected $data;

       public function __construct(DataRepositoryInterface $data) {
            $fractal = new Manager(); //or whatever gets an instance of a manager
            parent::__construct($fractal);
            $this->data = $data;        
        }
  }
```

Comment: They are of a different type (most likely) actually

Comment: Can you explain why passing the DataRepositoryInterface into the parent class would help?